# How to store youtube videos on my db

Tags: database, youtube, store

I want to get automatically latest youtube videos from a category (in 1hour checks)
and store the last 10 in db table,then with php to make mysql query to show the last 3 on my home page.i want to play the videos with myplayer and if it's too hard i will use the youtube one.
So for 12 hours = 120 videos automatically from 1 category and u can see latest 3 (from 12th hour) at my home page.

---

Okay so more details:
I found a rss feed with channel that  needed , i found a code but isn't really working:http://code.google.com/p/rssingest/
the code suppose to get rss info and store it into db and also the file contents  info how to add it into cron job, so i can use it automatically in eg. 1hour
so far i need help with this problem(**download the file and pls take a look before answer**):Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ....\index_clean.php on line 154

Comment: The question is how can i do this?

Comment: to increase the chances of it being answered: please include in your question how much of this you've already implemented, and where the immediate technical challenge lies. "a journey of a thousand miles begins with a single ... "

Answer (score 0):

These are just too many questions, with none properly asked. So I'll try to help with offering a couple of questions:

- how to download the content of an rss feed
- how to download a youtube video
- how to store streaming data in a file
- how to store a file in database
- how to stream data to a website
- how to play a video on a website
- how to setup a cron job
- how to retrieve the last n records from a table

Research each that you deem useful for you. Ask specific questions here. Include the results of your research.

Comment: 1st as i said i have the file to download content of an rss feed but there is one error returning.After i store the youtube url and name it's all i need then i can play the video and i know hot to retireve the last n records from table ,so far i just need help with error and then i will continue asking question .Sorry if i do anything wrong i am new here.